# why the $(function () executed always

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering why the `$(function () {}` is getting executed all the time. `function test(0` is not. what's the difference between those two?

Comment: This isn't very clear. Are you asking why the code inside `$(function() {}` is getting run when the page is loaded and a function called `test` is not getting run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery's extreme shorthand tends to trick the eye sometimes.

Look closely at the construct: A function named `$` gets called, *with the function  as an argument*. This is not equal to defining a function for later use like `function test() { .... }`

`$` is jQuery's "document ready" shortcut. The function passed to it will get executed once the document is loaded.

Answer (score 5):

this is a short form for document ready.

```
$("document").ready(function(){});
```

so it will execute every time document loads